# Django Query with multiple matches

Tags: python, django, postgresql-9.3

I have 2 lists, I can't process the logic in my head on what I'm supposed to do to complete the next step.

Versions:

```
Django 1.5.4
Python 2.7
PostgreSQL 9.3
```

Model:

```
class Channel(models.Model):
   contentlist = models.CharField(null=True,max_length=255555)

class Content(models.Model):
   contentid = UUIDField(unique=True,editable=False)
```

Table app_channel.entry1.contentlist:
`[u'3e46340c-9601-4183-9ffc-8de01e456686', u'7a413dd3-6aa8-4c49-be20-b6f4366c0801']`

Table app_content.entry1.channelid:
`3e46340c-9601-4183-9ffc-8de01e456686`

Table app_content.entry5.channelid:
`7a413dd3-6aa8-4c49-be20-b6f4366c0801`

I suppose I need a view query that returns a filtered query, but I'm not sure how to pick out the u''s specifically since it's not just an array I can loop a query for.

Also these results may have thousands of returns, so I need the most functional way of doing this. I don't expect anyone to write up the answer for me, but pointing me in the right direction would be amazing.

Thanks in advance to anyone that helps.

Comment: That's quite a long CharField. A TextField might be more suitable. Or if it is just a list of uuid's perhaps you'll reconsider the architecture?

Comment: @JohnMee As far as PostgreSQL is concerned there's no difference anyway. `text` and `varchar` are both aliases for the same text-holding varlena type. Does Django care?

Comment: it's a unique UUID, this has to be scalable as I said some responses are going to give 1000 valid responses out of multiple millions of options

Comment: Is the intention to find contentid's buried inside the contentlist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please don't store lists / arrays in character fields. It's a real pain, and you're only now starting to see the beginnings of it.

Use a side-table and join on it, like normal. Store pairs of `(channel_id, content_id)` in the side table.

If you're having performance issues with that, an alternative can be to use a PostgreSQL array-typed field. So you store your list of content as `uuid[]`. This is only useful if psycopg2 and Django's ORM thingy can understand and work with arrays, though. Depending on what you're doing, arrays (as opposed to a relational side table) can be a big performance gain, or a big performance downside. It depends a lot on the workload.

See [this related question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/55871/7788) which discusses comma-separated fields.

If you use arrays you can't do referential integrity checks properly, can't enforce uniqueness easily, etc. Additionally, when you update a small part of an array field of a tuple, **the whole tuple generally gets copied and written again** because of MVCC. So arrays can produce large *write amplification*, where small changes cause big writes.

On the other hand, using arrays improves data locality. If you have the main tuple it's much quicker to get the array. It's quite likely to be side-stored compressed in a TOAST table, but it's still all in one place, not potentially scattered across multiple blocks requiring index scans, joins, and filters to accumulate.

Unless you know just having a side table with a list of content-id won't perform well enough for you, that's what you should do. If you're having perf issues, look into proper indexing, vacuum, etc before looking at changing your data model to use arrays.

Comment: So create a new Model Class and instead of editing Channel.contentlist, just edit the appropriate table? Then queries to create my array would be off the new table? Is there a quick way to do table relations within Django? or would I have to query each contentid from new table to table Content to gain the other values? (This was what I was trying to keep light)

Comment: @AndrewWilson I don't really speak Django, but that sunds likely to be right, yes. As for the second question - sounds like you just want do do a join for that. I have no idea how to do joins in Django, but the docs will. In SQL, if I'm guessing what you want correctly, it'd be something like `SELECT content.*, channel.* FROM content INNER JOIN channel_content ON (channel_content.content_id = content.content_id) INNER JOIN channel ON (channel.channel_id = channel_content.channel_id)`. This is commonly referred to as a "join table" or "n:m link table".

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly the type of answer I was looking for. I will go down that route.

Comment: BTW, if you ever *did* have to store a `list` or other native Python object in a database field, you'd do it in a `bytea` field (`model.BinaryField`), storing the `pickle`'d python object. It's completely useless for querying when you do this as SQL code can't "see inside" the object, but it lets you store stuff that's just too hard to map onto relational tables when you're stuck.

Comment: I ended up doing a ManytoMany field relation to get this complete in Django.

Answer (score 1):

```
class Channel(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField()

class Content(models.Model):
   text = models.TextField()
   channel = models.ForeignKey(Channel)

channel = Channel.objects.get(name='foo')
for content in Content.objects.filter(channel=channel):
    print(content.text)
```

something like that... needs more work ;-)